# How to edit FreeBSD partition from Windows?

Tags: windows, read-write, ufs

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

I don't want only to read from an FreeBSD UFS but also write on it using Windows.

Comment: Windows has zero built-in support for UFS you would need to install third-party drivers to have that capability.

Comment: Something more informative? I really need to do this - otherwise I must use a usb to transfer data between OS'es which is not easy.

Comment: Use a NTFS partition to transfer data between the two operating system or purchase third-party software to add that capability

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy, while not really elegant:

- Install VirtualBox on Windows
- create a FreeBSD VM with a "Host Only" network
- Assign the partition in question to the VM as a virtual disk
- Install Samba on the FreeBSD VM and make it export that disk

You can now access the Samba share from Windows, in effect reading from and writing to the UFS partition.